# Suitable Design pattern for multi module web application

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications

I would like to know the best design pattern for handling multi module web application.

Example :- A REST web services project will handle different type of requests to send SMS.

Types of requests

1. Individual SMS trigger
2. Promotional SMS trigger
3. Interactive SMS trigger
4. Scheduled SMS trigger

there are different types of SMS to be sent and each type has its own business logic to be applied before triggering the SMS.
which is the suitable design pattern to handle it?

Please  provide your suggestion or links , it will be of great help for designing our project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly if that's the only scope of your application, keep it simple, don't get carried away trying to over-engineer or implement bunch design patterns unnecessarily.

> there are different types of SMS to be sent and each type has its own
>   business logic to be applied before triggering the SMS

You have not mentioned how business logic differs based on SMS type. So in the simplest form you can start like this:

```
public interface ISMSService 
{
    void Send();
}

// One class for each SMS type
public class IndividualSMS : ISMSService 
{
    public IndividualSMS(<paramters>) {
        // <parameters> can be different based on SMS type
    }

    public void Send() {
        // Implement SMS type specific logic
    }
}

public class SMSManager {
    private readonly ISMSService smsService;

    // Inject ISMSService implementation from calling code
    public SMSManager(ISMSService smsService) {
        this.smsService = smsService;
    }

    public void SendSMS() {
        this.smsService.Send();
    }
}

// Client code
var individualSMS = new IndividualSMS(<parameters>); // Use DI container for resolving
var smsManager = new SMSManager(individualSMS);
```